# Normal Mapping Issues

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I'm attempting to implement normal mapping into my glsl shaders for the first time. I've written an ObjLoader that calculates the Tangents and Bitangents - I then pass the relevant information to my shaders (I'll show code in a bit). However, when I run the program, my models end up looking like this:

[image]

Looks great, I know, but not quite what I am trying to achieve!
I understand that I should be simply calculating direction vectors and not moving the vertices - but it seems somewhere down the line I end up making that mistake.

I am unsure if I am making the mistake when reading my .obj file and calculating the tangent/bitangent vectors, or if the mistake is happening within my Vertex/Fragment Shader.

Now for my code:

In my ObjLoader - when I come across a face, I calculate the deltaPositions and deltaUv vectors for all three vertices of the face - and then calculate the tangent and bitangent vectors:

[image]

I then organize the vertex data collected to construct my list of indices - and in that process I restructure the tangent and bitangent vectors to respect the newly constructed indice list.

[image]

Lastly - I perform Orthogonalization and calcuate the final bitangent vector.

[image]

After binding the VAO, VBO, IBO, and passing all the information respectively - my shader calculations are as follows:

Vertex Shader:

```
void main()
{
    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(pos, 1.0);

    // Position of the vertex, in world space 
    v_Position = (M * vec4(pos, 0.0)).xyz;

    vec4 bitan = V * M * vec4(bitangent, 0.0);
    vec4 tang = V * M * vec4(tangent, 0.0);
    vec4 norm = vec4(normal, 0.0);

    mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(tang.xyz, bitan.xyz, norm.xyz));

    // Vector that goes from the vertex to the camera, in camera space
    vec3 vPos_cameraspace = (V * M * vec4(pos, 1.0)).xyz;
    camdir_cameraspace = normalize(-vPos_cameraspace);

    // Vector that goes from the vertex to the light, in camera space
    vec3 lighPos_cameraspace = (V * vec4(lightPos_worldspace, 0.0)).xyz;
    lightdir_cameraspace = normalize((lighPos_cameraspace - vPos_cameraspace));

    v_TexCoord = texcoord;

    lightdir_tangentspace = TBN * lightdir_cameraspace;
    camdir_tangentspace = TBN * camdir_cameraspace;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
void main()
{
    // Light Emission Properties
    vec3 LightColor = (CalcDirectionalLight()).xyz;
    float LightPower = 20.0;

    // Cutting out texture 'black' areas of texture
    vec4 tempcolor = texture(AlbedoTexture, v_TexCoord);
    if (tempcolor.a < 0.5)
        discard;

    // Material Properties
    vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = tempcolor.rgb;
    vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = material.ambient * MaterialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    // Local normal, in tangent space
    vec3 TextureNormal_tangentspace = normalize(texture(NormalTexture, v_TexCoord)).rgb;
    TextureNormal_tangentspace = (TextureNormal_tangentspace * 2.0) - 1.0;

    // Distance to the light
    float distance = length(lightPos_worldspace - v_Position);

    // Normal of computed fragment, in camera space
    vec3 n = TextureNormal_tangentspace;

    // Direction of light (from the fragment)
    vec3 l = normalize(TextureNormal_tangentspace);

    // Find angle between normal and light
    float cosTheta = clamp(dot(n, l), 0, 1);

    // Eye Vector (towards the camera)
    vec3 E = normalize(camdir_tangentspace);

    // Direction in which the triangle reflects the light
    vec3 R = reflect(-l, n);

    // Find angle between eye vector and reflect vector
    float cosAlpha = clamp(dot(E, R), 0, 1);

    color = 
            MaterialAmbientColor + 
            MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance * distance) +
            MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha, 5) / (distance * distance);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot 1 obvious mistake in your code. `TBN` is generated by the `bitangent`, `tangent` and `normal`. While the `bitangent` and `tangent` are transformed from model space to view space, the `normal` is not transformed. That does not make any sense. All the 3 vetors have to be related to the same coordinate system:

```c
vec4 bitan = V * M * vec4(bitangent, 0.0);
vec4 tang  = V * M * vec4(tangent, 0.0);
vec4 norm  = V * M * vec4(normal, 0.0);

mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(tang.xyz, bitan.xyz, norm.xyz));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With this adjustment, as well as grouping my tangent/bitangent vectors inside my Vertex struct instead of their own arrays, seemed to fix the issue! Thank you for your help!